# Dictionary<string, city>

Tags: c#

Through Loop populated dictionary and display the following text “[City] is a city in [Province]” replacing [City] with the city name and [Province] with the province name. How to replace the names.

```
        Dictionary<string, City> city = new Dictionary<string, City>();
        city.Add("Toronto", new City("Ontario", 20000));
        city.Add("Vancover", new City("B.C", 40000));
        city.Add("Winnipeg", new City("Manitoba", 10000));
        Console.WriteLine("Details of Provinces :- City, Province and Popullation");

        foreach (var City in city)
          Console.WriteLine(City.ToString());
```

// it prints detail but not in like- Toronto is a city in Ontario.

or

```
foreach (var City in city)
   Console.WriteLine("{0} is a city in {1},"City.ToString());// but it throws error index 0`
```

Comment: You must show "Key" and "Value". "Key" is your city, and "Value" is your province and population.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code won't compile because `City` in your loop is not a `City` object, it is a `KeyValuePair<string, City>`.  Your loop could look something like this:

```
foreach (var pair in city)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is a city in {1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
}
```

I would note it does seem like `City` isn't named correctly, it seems `Province` might be a better name.

Comment: Thanks It works. How to replace these cities according to the population.

Comment: I don't follow.  Replace them with what?

Comment: i want to sort cities according to their population.

Comment: That's rather different to replacing them! Replacing `city` with `city.OrderBy(x => x.Value.Population)` (assuming that population is exposed as a property) should sort the key-value pairs by population.